# Docker sempre verifica se a imagem local é de versão igual ou inferior a do repositório oficial Docker Hub?

Tags: docker

Ao levantar uma nova aplicação, não se tem a imagem localmente, então o Docker vai buscar a imagem que é a base do container. Uma vez que foi feito o download da imagem, Docker sobe o container. A aplicação está lá funcionando. Mas caso exista localmente a imagem que foi base para um outro container, se for antiga, como o Docker trata essa parte ao levantar a nova aplicação? Pega a imagem antiga, atualiza e roda o novo container? Gostaria de entender esse processo todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos começar pelo comando `run`. Ao rodar `docker run ubuntu` o docker irá verificar se há localmente uma imagem do ubuntu utilizando a tag `:latest`. Caso haja o docker irá criar um container utilizando esta imagem, se não ele irá realizar o `docker pull ubuntu:latest` e, após isso, criar o container.

Ao rodar o comando `docker pull ubuntu` ele irá verificar se há uma imagem do ubuntu com a tag `:latest`, em caso negativo ele irá baixar a imagem. Caso, ao rodar o `docker pull` ele encontre uma imagem local com a tag `:latest` então irá baixar a assinatura da imagem(um hash em sha256) que está la no DockerHub e irá comparar com a assinatura da sua imagem local, se forem iguais ele imprime no console algo como:

```
status: Image is up to date for ubuntu:latest
```

Caso sejam diferentes ele irá baixar a nova imagem e marcará a antiga com a tag `<none>`, ficando algo parecido com isto:

```
Repository            tag                 Image ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu               latest              113a43faa138        2 weeks ago         81.2MB
ubuntu               <none>              452a96d81c30        7 weeks ago         79.6MB
```

Comment: Uhmmm. Show! Daí o novo projeto irá usar a última versão. Se eu levantar o projeto antigo, ele também rodará com base na última?  O <none> fica tipo estacionado, sem utilidade? Sei que seria outra pergunta. Mas valeu!

Comment: quando uma imagem fica com essa tag `<none>` não serve de nada, só ocupa espaço em disco pois o docker não utiliza ela para gerar um novo container. Se você atualizar uma imagem o docker sempre utilizará a mais nova(a imagem local com a tag especificada) para criar novos containers.